# JavaScript objects as property of object reference

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to understand how objects work in JS.

```
const obj = { inner: { a: 'Hello' } };

const clone = { ...obj };

// obj === clone -> false
// !!! BUT !!!
// obj.inner === clone.inner -> true

clone.inner = { a: 'world' };
// obj === { inner: { a: 'Hello' } }
// clone === { inner: { a: 'World' } }
```

Is there a documentation on this behaviour? Can I rely on inner objects references equality while creating new object via spread operator?

Comment: only the outer objects are cloned with spread operator. the inner objects will still be references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`...` [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) creates a shallow copy anything deeper then level one will still stays as reference to original object

```js
const obj = { inner: { a: 'Hello' } };

const clone = { ...obj };


console.log(obj === clone)

console.log(obj.inner === clone.inner)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shallow Cloning
If the item being spread into the target is an object, only a reference to that object will be copied. The spread operator will not recursively deep clone properties. In addition, only own, enumerable properties are copied.

This Post will help [Link](https://codeburst.io/master-javascripts-object-spread-operator-3803430e99aa)

Comment: I found more detailed answer [here](https://itnext.io/why-concept-of-immutability-is-so-damn-important-for-a-beginner-front-end-developer-8da85b565c8e) in the drawbacks section.