# update the value of nested objects using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-state

For form validation, I am using useState hooks. Below is the code

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingAddress.address)
  const [city, setCity] = useState(shippingAddress.city)
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState(shippingAddress.postalCode)
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(shippingAddress.country)

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    formErrors: { address: '', city: '', postalCode: '', country: '' },
    addressValid: false,
    cityValid: false,
    postalCodeValid: false,
    countryValid: false,
    formValid: false,
  })

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    const prevState = { ...formState }
    if (address === '') {
      prevState.formErrors.address = 'address not valid'
      prevState.addressValid = false
      setFormState(prevState)
    }
```

code continues...

I am having trouble to update the formErrors.address value. It shows errors in the browser as:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'address' of undefined

useEffect(() => {
  const prevState = { ...formState }
   if (address === '') {
      prevState.formErrors.address = 'address not valid'
      prevState.addressValid = false
     setFormState(prevState)
  }
```

Comment: console.log(prevState) before using

Comment: The code you have shared cannot be the source of this bug since it does not include code that might assign formErrors to null/undefined.

Somewhere in your code formErrors is being set to null/undefined. Please provide the rest of the code to see where formErrors is being set to null.

Also as a side note you are mutating state because formErrors is an object and prevState has the same reference to the formErrors object. Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171407/javascript-objects-as-property-of-object-reference.

```const prevState = { ...formState }```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, we'd need to see the code where you are setting your assignments, but in the `useEffect` you can clean up some of the confusion by using the `prevState` (which is actually current state) baked into `useState`.  Then, you really only care when the `address` changes, rather than having this run every time.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (address === '') {
     setFormState(prevState =>( {
       ...prevState,
       formErrors.address = 'address not valid',
       addressValid: false
       }))
  },[address])
```

Comment: is `formErrors.address = 'address not valid',` valid in that location?

Comment: also, to return an object literal in an arrow function like that, you need to wrap it in `()`